# apt Repositories - How to Choose the Right One for Lubuntu

Tags: apt, package-management, lubuntu

I have limited knowledge in the Linux kernel.  More specifically, I lack familiarity with the different past builds of Ubuntu (and how that interacts with the flavor I am currently using).

I am using a Lubuntu 15.10 machine onto wish I wish to install `wview`.  The question is the following: What repo should I use when offered the following choices?:

```
For ubuntu/kubuntu lucid:
deb http://www.wviewweather.com/apt/lucid lucid main
deb-src http://www.wviewweather.com/apt/lucid lucid main

For ubuntu/kubuntu precise:
deb http://www.wviewweather.com/apt/precise precise main
deb-src http://www.wviewweather.com/apt/precise precise main

For ubuntu/kubuntu quantal:
deb http://www.wviewweather.com/apt/quantal quantal main
deb-src http://www.wviewweather.com/apt/quantal quantal main

For ubuntu/kubuntu raring:
deb http://www.wviewweather.com/apt/raring raring main
deb-src http://www.wviewweather.com/apt/raring raring main

For ubuntu/kubuntu saucy:
deb http://www.wviewweather.com/apt/saucy saucy main
deb-src http://www.wviewweather.com/apt/saucy saucy main
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you need to pick a source that does not support your version number get the one nearest to your version.

Ubuntu names are in alphabetical order so "saucy" would be the newest. Besides that you can also always opt for the one from the newest LTS. That would be 14.04: Trusty.

BUT in this case I would advice to NOT use any of these sources. From the versions they support Saucy is the newest and that has gone end of life a long long long long time ago. It is from 2013 and the least your should aim for is the latest LTS (14.04).

===

[See their website](http://www.wviewweather.com/release-notes/wview-Debian-Quick-Start.html) and opt for the 'source' install from this location:

```
http://sourceforge.net/projects/wview/files/wview/wview-install-debian/download
```

That should download `wview-5.21.7.tar.gz` and you can do the generic "make/configure". (their is an HTML in the file that has your sources so you probably might have already seen this).

Comment: Ha!  I did not know/realize the alphabetical thing.  So: using wily, from which 'threshold version' should I be make'ing from source, in general?  Thanks.

Comment: 14.04 LTS should be the minimum. Releases after a LTS are strongly related to that version (so 15.04. 15.10 have 14.04 as their base and 14.04 hardware stack is updated so it keeps close to 15.04 and now 15.10). That software is old... I would not install it. I see pages on that website with a last change from 2009... far too old to be thrustworthy  ;-)

Comment: Ok, I'll always refer to active LTS which makes a lot of sense.  I didn't realize the software was so old, but I'll give it a try anyhow; it's my best shot at learning how to handle `/dev/usb/hiddev0` with `Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1941:8021 Dream Link WH1080 Weather Station / USB Missile Launcher` (for the moment, at least).

Answer (score 0):

You want to select a repository that matches the version of Lubuntu that you are running. `lsb_release --codename` (and `man lsb_release`) will show you.

On MY system (YMMV), I get:

```
$ lsb_release --codename
Codename:   trusty
```